# How can I optimize (minimize) the output of a machine leaning model?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-optimization

The situation is the following:
A want to optimize a process which takes wax to create wax products. For each product to be made, there is a different composition of wax, and a set o parameters for the process (machine configurations). During the process, some objects are discarded due to manufacturing defects.

My first idea is to create a supervised machine leaning model that takes the wax composition and machine configurations as inputs, and the number of wasted objects as output (I have the data to do this).

My problem is: after creating that model, how do I  find the optimal process parameters (machine configuration) to minimize the number of wasted objects, for a given wax composition (it can be a new composition, never seen before).

The problem with a better formulation:

I have a vector of features for the machine settings s = [s1, s2, … , sn], a vector of features for the wax composition w = [w1, w2, … , wm] and for different combinations of s and w I have a associated cost J.

I have a database of training examples relating different vectors s and w with a cost J.

With this data, I would like to create a system where I would input a vector w, and the system would output a vector s, such that s minimizes the cost J, for that specific vector w.

Sorry for the lack of a precise formulation.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. Bring some code and we can try to help.

Comment: One often used approach is to estimate some response surface (using statistics) and then optimize this response function.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a linear programming problem (like simplex for example) which does precisely that: minimize(or maximize) an objective function with defined parameters(in your case machine configuration).(This is not directly related to the ML idea)

Comment: Thanks for replying, Luis.

The problem with a better formulation:

I have a vector of features for the machine settings s = [s1, s2, … , sn], a vector of features for the wax composition w = [w1, w2, … , wm] and for different combinations of s and w I have a associated cost J.

I have a database of training examples relating different vectors s and w with a cost J.

With this data, I would like to create a system where I would input a vector w, and the system would output a vector s, such that s minimizes the cost J, for that specific vector w.